# DDD in SF3 folder structure

Tags: php, domain-driven-design, symfony

I am thinking through an ad website where Users can login, post new Listings and search existing ones. I am going to make this my first project following DDD principles completely. I have never done any DDD in Symfony before.

Below are my thoughts about this. Could you please tell me if this is correct and advice on better ways?

I can see two domains: User and Listing

Searching/displaying/posting functionality will live in Listing domain. Logging in/out live in a User domain.

SF3 directory example structure is

```
app/
   ListingBundle/
      src/
         Listing.php
         SearchService.php
         ListingRepositoryInterface.php
         Controller/
            public/
               ListingController.php
            protected/
               ListingController.php
         Resource/
           view/
              public/
                 detail.twig.html
              protected/
                 edit.twig.html

   UserBundle/
      src/
         User.php
         AuthService.php
         UserRepositoryInterface.php
         Controller/
            public/
               UserController.php
            protected/
               UserController.php
         Resource/
           view/
              public/
                 login.twig.html
              protected/
                 dashboard.twig.html

   PersistenceBundle
       src/
          UserRepository.php
          ListingRepository.php
```

My main questions are:

- Is this structure correct?
- Is it a good idea to have separate protected and public controllers with the same name?
- Where do things go like a page on the User backend part of the website showing recent Listings posted by the User? Where is the boundary between those two domains?
- Is PersistenceBundle a good idea or should I have persistence live inside User and Listing bundle?

Comment: Pure Domain Driven Design focuses on complex domain logic.  Might be useful to layout what your domain business logic might look like first.  Controllers and views should just be a minor implementation detail.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Frameworks & DDD

You make a wrong assumption here, which is **"I am going to use the Symfony framework to implement my app in a DDD-ish way"**.

Don't do this, [**Frameworks are just an implementation detail**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QaIGN_cTcc8) and provide one (ore more) delivery methods for your **Application**. And I mean Application here in the context of the [**Hexagonal Architecture**](http://alistair.cockburn.us/Hexagonal+architecture).

If you look at the following example from one of our contexts you see that our `ApiClient` context contains three layers (top-level directory structure). **Application** (contains the use case services), **Domain** (contains the models and behaviour) and **Infrastructure** (contains infrastructure concerns like persistence and delivery). I focused on the Symfony integration and the persistence here, since this is what the OP's original question was about:

```
src/ApiClient
├── Application
│   ├── ApiClient
│   │   ├── CreateApiClient
│   │   ├── DisableApiClient
│   │   ├── EnableApiClient
│   │   ├── GetApiClient
│   │   ├── ListApiClient
│   │   ├── RemoveApiClient
│   │   └── ChangeApiClientDetails
│   ├── ClientIpAddress
│   │   ├── BlackListClientIpAddress
│   │   ├── CreateClientIpAddress
│   │   ├── ListByApiClientId
│   │   ├── ListClientIpAddresses
│   │   └── WhiteListClientIpAddress
│   └── InternalContactPerson
│       ├── CreateInternalContactPerson
│       ├── GetInternalContactPerson
│       ├── GetByApiClientId
│       ├── ListContacts
│       ├── ReassignApiClient
│       └── Remove
├── Domain
│   └── Model
│       ├── ApiClient
│       ├── ClientIpAddress
│       └── InternalContactPerson
└── Infrastructure
    ├── Delivery
    │   └── Http
    │       └── SymfonyBundle
    │           ├── Controller
    │           │   ├── ApiClientController.php
    │           │   ├── InternalContactController.php
    │           │   └── IpAddressController.php
    │           ├── DependencyInjection
    │           │   ├── Compiler
    │           │   │   ├── EntityManagerPass.php
    │           │   │   └── RouterPass.php
    │           │   ├── Configuration.php
    │           │   ├── MetadataLoader
    │           │   │   ├── Adapter
    │           │   │   │   ├── HateoasSerializerAdapter.php
    │           │   │   │   └── JMSSerializerBuilderAdapter.php
    │           │   │   ├── Exception
    │           │   │   │   ├── AmbiguousNamespacePathException.php
    │           │   │   │   ├── EmptyMetadataDirectoryException.php
    │           │   │   │   ├── FileException.php
    │           │   │   │   ├── MalformedNamespaceException.php
    │           │   │   │   └── MetadataLoadException.php
    │           │   │   ├── FileMetadataLoader.php
    │           │   │   ├── MetadataAware.php
    │           │   │   └── MetadataLoaderInterface.php
    │           │   └── MFBApiClientExtension.php
    │           ├── DTO
    │           │   └── ApiClient
    │           │       └── ChangeInternalContact
    │           │           ├── ChangeInternalContactRequest.php
    │           │           └── ChangeInternalContactResponse.php
    │           ├── MFBApiClientBundle.php
    │           ├── Resources
    │           │   ├── config
    │           │   │   ├── domain_services.yml
    │           │   │   ├── metadata_loader.yml
    │           │   │   ├── routing.yml
    │           │   │   └── services.yml
    │           │   ├── hateoas
    │           │   │   └── ApiClient
    │           │   │       ├── Application
    │           │   │       │   ├── ApiClient
    │           │   │       │   │   ├── CreateApiClient
    │           │   │       │   │   │   └── CreateApiClientResponse.yml
    │           │   │       │   │   └── ListApiClient
    │           │   │       │   │       └── ListApiClientResponse.yml
    │           │   │       │   ├── ClientIpAddress
    │           │   │       │   │   ├── CreateClientIpAddress
    │           │   │       │   │   │   └── CreateClientIpAddressResponse.yml
    │           │   │       │   │   ├── ListByApiClientId
    │           │   │       │   │   │   └── ListByApiClientIdResponse.yml
    │           │   │       │   │   └── ListClientIpAddresses
    │           │   │       │   │       └── ListClientIpAddressesResponse.yml
    │           │   │       │   └── InternalContactPerson
    │           │   │       │       ├── Create
    │           │   │       │       │   └── CreateResponse.yml
    │           │   │       │       └── List
    │           │   │       │           └── ListResponse.yml
    │           │   │       └── Domain
    │           │   │           ├── ApiClient
    │           │   │           │   └── ApiClient.yml
    │           │   │           ├── ClientIpAddress
    │           │   │           │   └── ClientIpAddress.yml
    │           │   │           └── InternalContactPerson
    │           │   │               └── InternalContactPerson.yml
    │           │   └── serializer
    │           │       ├── ApiClient
    │           │       │   ├── Application
    │           │       │   │   ├── ApiClient
    │           │       │   │   │   ├── CreateApiClient
    │           │       │   │   │   │   ├── ContactPersonRequest.yml
    │           │       │   │   │   │   ├── CreateApiClientRequest.yml
    │           │       │   │   │   │   └── CreateApiClientResponse.yml
    │           │       │   │   │   └── GetApiClient
    │           │       │   │   │       └── GetApiClientResponse.yml
    │           │       │   │   ├── ClientIpAddress
    │           │       │   │   │   └── CreateClientIpAddress
    │           │       │   │   │       ├── CreateClientIpAddressRequest.yml
    │           │       │   │   │       └── CreateClientIpAddressResponse.yml
    │           │       │   │   └── InternalContactPerson
    │           │       │   │       ├── Create
    │           │       │   │       │   ├── CreateRequest.yml
    │           │       │   │       │   └── CreateResponse.yml
    │           │       │   │       ├── Get
    │           │       │   │       │   └── GetResponse.yml
    │           │       │   │       ├── List
    │           │       │   │       │   └── ListResponse.yml
    │           │       │   │       └── ReassignApiClient
    │           │       │   │           └── ReassignApiClientRequest.yml
    │           │       │   └── Domain
    │           │       │       ├── ApiClient
    │           │       │       │   ├── ApiClient.yml
    │           │       │       │   └── ContactPerson.yml
    │           │       │       ├── ClientIpAddress
    │           │       │       │   └── ClientIpAddress.yml
    │           │       │       └── InternalContactPerson
    │           │       │           └── InternalContactPerson.yml
    │           │       └── Bundle
    │           │           └── DTO
    │           │               └── ApiClient
    │           │                   └── ChangeInternalContact
    │           │                       └── ChangeInternalContactRequest.yml
    │           └── Service
    │               └── Hateoas
    │                   └── UrlGenerator.php
    └── Persistence
        ├── Doctrine
        │   ├── ApiClient
        │   │   ├── ApiClientRepository.php
        │   │   └── mapping
        │   │       ├── ApiClientId.orm.yml
        │   │       ├── ApiClient.orm.yml
        │   │       ├── CompanyName.orm.yml
        │   │       ├── ContactEmail.orm.yml
        │   │       ├── ContactList.orm.yml
        │   │       ├── ContactName.orm.yml
        │   │       ├── ContactPerson.orm.yml
        │   │       ├── ContactPhone.orm.yml
        │   │       └── ContractReference.orm.yml
        │   ├── ClientIpAddress
        │   │   ├── ClientIpAddressRepository.php
        │   │   └── mapping
        │   │       ├── ClientIpAddressId.orm.yml
        │   │       ├── ClientIpAddress.orm.yml
        │   │       └── IpAddress.orm.yml
        │   └── InternalContactPerson
        │       ├── InternalContactPersonRepository.php
        │       └── mapping
        │           ├── InternalContactPersonId.orm.yml
        │           └── InternalContactPerson.orm.yml
        └── InMemory
            ├── ApiClient
            │   └── ApiClientRepository.php
            ├── ClientIpAddress
            │   └── ClientIpAddressRepository.php
            └── InternalContactPerson
                └── InternalContactPersonRepository.php

94 directories, 145 files
```

Quite a lot of files!

You can see that I am using the bundle as a **Port** of the Application (the naming is a little bit of though, it should not be `Http` delivery, since in the strict sense of the **Hexagonal Architecture** it is an **App-To-App Port**). I strongly advise you to read the [**DDD in PHP book**](https://leanpub.com/ddd-in-php) where all these concepts are actually explained with expressive examples in PHP (assuming you have read the blue book and the red book already, although this book works as a standalone while still making references).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I like the idea of having a Port, thus decoupling the app from a framework completely. I am not getting though where authentication functionilty would go - does it belong to the core or application domain?

Answer (score 6):

**A folder structure for DDD applications built with Symfony**

I second tPl0ch's answer, but would like to propose a slight variant of the folder structure which has been useful in a couple of projects with Symfony where I was involved in. For your specific domain the folder structure could look as follows:

```
app
    Listing
        Domain
            Model
                Listing.php
            Repository
                ListingRepository.php
            Service
                SearchService.php
        Infrastructure
            Repository
                DoctrineListingRepository.php   // or some other implementation
            Resources
                // symfony & doctrine config etc.
            Service
                ElasticSearchService.php        // or some other implementation
            ListingInfrastructureBundle.php
        Presentation
            Controller
                ViewListingController.php       // assuming this is the "public" part
                EditListingController.php       // assuming this is the "protected" part
            Forms
                ListingForm.php
            Resources
                // symfony config & views etc.
            ListingPresentationBundle.php
    User
        // ...
        Infrastructure
            Service
                AuthService.php
        // ...
```

With this folder structure, you separate the different layers of the [onion architecture](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/). The different folders clearly communicate the boundaries and allowed dependencies between the layers. I have written a blog post on [DDD folder structures with Symfony](http://www.fabian-keller.de/blog/domain-driven-design-with-symfony-a-folder-structure) which describes the approach in detail.

---

**Additional Resources:**

Apart from that, I also recommend to have a look at the following resources:

- [PHP DDD Cargo Sample](https://github.com/codeliner/php-ddd-cargo-sample): PHP 7 Version of the cargo sample used in Eric Evans DDD book
- [Sylius](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius): eCommerce PHP framework built on top of Symfony with component-based architecture

I have learned a lot from understanding the Sylius code base - it is a real world project and is fairly huge. They have all kinds of tests and have put a lot of effort into shipping high quality code.

Comment: With a structure like this, where would you place a shared service, such as a hash handler, or JSON encoder?